# Where is sample erlang code for rabbitmq's file operation?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, file-transfer

I want to transfer files in rabbitmq and found message record in the rabbit_framing.hrl file as follows. But there is no explanation guide for these messages. 
Is it low efficient for using these messages or I haven't found the related information?

Could you give me some sample code for using the messages?

```
-record('file.qos', {prefetch_size = 0, prefetch_count = 0, global = false}).
-record('file.qos_ok', {}).
-record('file.consume', {ticket = 1, queue = <<"">>, consumer_tag = <<"">>, no_local = false, no_ack = false, exclusive = false, nowait = false}).
-record('file.consume_ok', {consumer_tag}).
-record('file.cancel', {consumer_tag, nowait = false}).
-record('file.cancel_ok', {consumer_tag}).
-record('file.open', {identifier, content_size}).
-record('file.open_ok', {staged_size}).
-record('file.stage', {}).
-record('file.publish', {ticket = 1, exchange = <<"">>, routing_key = <<"">>, mandatory = false, immediate = false, identifier}).
-record('file.return', {reply_code = 200, reply_text = <<"">>, exchange, routing_key}).
-record('file.deliver', {consumer_tag, delivery_tag, redelivered = false, exchange, routing_key, identifier}).
-record('file.ack', {delivery_tag = 0, multiple = false}).
-record('file.reject', {delivery_tag, requeue = true}).
```